# how to create a constructor in flutter with null safety

Tags: flutter, dart

This got a bit tricky for me. since we can no longer pass null values in contructor I had this

```
class LeadingButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData icon;
  final Color color;
  final Color iconColor;
  final double iconSize;
  final double size;
  final Color backGroundColor;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  final double padding;
  final EdgeInsets margin;
  final double rotate;

  LeadingButton({
      @required this.icon,
      this.color = Colors.transparent,
      @required this.onPressed,
      this.size = 20,
      this.backGroundColor = Colors.transparent,
      this.iconSize = 20,
      this.iconColor = darkColor,
      this.rotate = 0,
      this.padding = 0,
      this.margin = const EdgeInsets.all(10)});
...
```

I am getting an error on `icon` and `onpressed` function. although the
documentation is saying

> The parameter 'onPressed' & 'icon' can't have a value
> of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is
> 'null'. Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the
> 'required' modifier.

I guess I am missing some thing, kindly mind to share

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, but it could be that this is due to the recent change of the keyword.
Did you try the `required` keyword instead?

https://dart.dev/null-safety/faq#how-does-required-compare-to-the-new-required-keyword

Answer (score 1):

I think that **LeadingButton**'s **onPressed** type needs to be changed to **VoidCallback?** so it can accept null values.

Comment: it's type is `VoidCallBack` also is `required modifier` mean something else than putting a `@required` in front

Comment: is LeadingButton class of your own? Or it is from lib that you have no control of?

Comment: its mine and the above is its constructor